# Quem quebra este galho — qual a origem dos significados figurados de «galho»?

Tags: etimologia, português-brasileiro

No outro dia li aqui no Portuguese Language a expressão *quebra-galho* (*desenrasca* em Portugal). Acho que já tinha ouvido. Mas fui ver ao dicionário e verifiquei de *galho* tem no Brasil uma porção de significados figurados. Podem ver [*galho* no Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/galho), e eu deixo aqui as definições do Houaiss (Lisboa 2003):

> **1** divisão ou subdivisão do caule das árvores ou arbustos
>   **2** toco que fica na árvore depois de partido o ramo
>   **3** esse ramo partido, desprendido da árvore
>   **4** corno (‘apêndice ósseo’)
>   **5** *B infrm* emprego ou ocupação subsidiária; biscate
>   **6** *B infrm* situação difícil; complicação
>   **7** *B infrm* falta de entendimento; confusão, briga
>   **8** *B infrm* relação extraconjugal
>   *galhos* **9** *B* conjunto de riachos que, nas cabeceiras, se reúnem para formar um rio

Depois há entre outras duas expressões que parecem claramente relacionadas com com a aceção **6** e possivelmente com a **7** (ainda do Houaiss):

> **dar (um) galho**  *B infrm* ocasionar dificuldades, complicações, aborrecimentos
>   **quebrar um galho** *B infrm* ajudar a resolver, ainda que precária e/ou provisoriamente, uma dificuldade

A aceção **9**, *riachos*, parece ser uma simples analogia com os ramos de uma árvore, e o **4**, *corno*, possivelmente também. Já as aceções **5** a **8** são mais curiosas. O Houaiss dá 1562 como o ano da primeira ocorrência conhecida de *galho*. Há na internet umas histórias acerca da origem de *quebrar um galho* [(exemplo)](http://guiadoestudante.abril.com.br/aventuras-historia/quebrar-galho-474620.shtml), mas, como de costume, sem apresentarem qualquer fundamentação ou datas do surgimento.

E o que eu gostava de saber é quando apareceram no registo escrito as várias aceções, incluindo as expressões *dar galho* e *quebrar um galho*. E se for possível esclarecer como é esses significados apareceram, ainda melhor.

Comment: É interessante o uso do pretérito imperfeito do indicativo ("eu gostava de saber") ao invés do futuro do pretérito (eu gostaria de saber) em pt-PT. Raramente ouço tal uso em pt-BR.

Comment: Eu diria que a ace[p?]ção **6** é a mais comum no Brasil hoje em dia, entre as figuradas, e justamente por causa da expressão *quebra-galho*. As outras, para serem compreendidas (por mim) dependem muito do contexto.

Comment: @bfavaretto Também era a única que eu conhecia, e só do Brasil. *Acepção* é ptBR (e ptPT pré-AO); *aceção* é pt PT pós-AO (mesmo antes do AO, não pronunciávamos o ***p***).

Answer (score 1):

Desconheço a origem da expressão, mas numa rápida pesquisa na internet, encontrei uma série de sites educacionais brasileiros que dizem haver 2 origens:

1) Galho também representa ramos de um rio. E quebrar um galho teria surgido como forma de cortar caminho, uma espécie de atalho. Assim eu interpreto como se beneficiar mas com o uso de um atalho.

2) Uma entidade de religião afro, que domina as matas, poderia livrar alguém dos galhos ao atravessar uma mata.

**Referências**:

- [guiadoestudante.abril.com.br](http://origin.guiadoestudante.abril.com.br/aventuras-historia/quebrar-galho-474620.shtml)
- [brasilescola.uol.com.br](https://www.google.com.br/amp/m.brasilescola.uol.com.br/amp/curiosidades/quebrar-um-galho.htm)
- [dicas de português](http://g1.globo.com/educacao/blog/dicas-de-portugues/post/qual-e-origem-das-expressoes-2.html)

**Galho como "ramos de um rio"**:

Definição de galhos (no plural) em https://www.dicio.com.br/galho:

> Conjunto de riachos que, nas cabeceiras, se reúnem para formar um rio.

Comment: Conseguiste descobrir quando é que os vários sentidos aparecem no registro escrito? Eu escolhi fazer dessa a pergunta principal porque ela é em princípio possível de responder mais ou menos objetivamente, ao passo muitas vezes não se consegue saber o porquê do surgimento do sentido; para já parece ser esse o caso do *galho*; nenhum dos sites diz no que é que se baseiam as "explicações" da origem.

Comment: Não consegui ir tão fundo. Até considerei postar como comentário mas acabou ficando mais com cara de resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Ainda na época da escravatura brasileira, era uma prática comum de **punir os escravos com galhos, surrando-os até que o galho quebrasse**. Os escravos rapidamente começaram a enfraquecer todos os galho que poderiam ser usados para tal prática, logo o termo **"quebrar o galho"** ficou rapidamente associado com um alívio de dor, e resolução de problemas.

Comment: Teria alguma fonte que reforce sua resposta?